# Pass reactive data to Meteor Template

Tags: meteor

I need track change on data passing to template

Example

```
{{>myTemplate data1="staticData" data2=reactiveHelper }}
```

Where data1 is static bu data2 come from a helper in parent template like:

```
Template.parentTemplate.helper({
    'reactiveHelper':function(){
        return Session.get('any-reactive-value')
    }
})
```

Then I need a a autorun who track myTemplate.data.data2

Thanks for any help and sorry for my english

Comment: Why can't you read that Session directly inside your `myTemplate` using a helper?

Comment: @RaduChiriac speak the truth.

Comment: Because is a package, and I want use a clean API.
I provisionally  solved passing a function
Template.parentTemplate.helper({
    'reactiveHelper':function(){
        return :function(){
           return Session.get('any-reactive-value')
       }
    }
})